# ACF by group in R

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to calculate the acf of a time series grouped by a grouping variable. Specifically, I have a data frame contaning a single time series (variable a) and a grouping variable (e. g. weekday, variable b). Here is an example:

```
data <- data.frame(a=rnorm(1:150), b=rep(rep(1:3, each=5), 10))
```

Now, I would like to calculate the acf for the different values of the grouping variable. For example, for lag 2 and group 1 I would like to get the correlation between t and t-2 calculated only over time points t with b=1 (the value of b for t-2 does not matter). I know that the function acf can easily calculate the acf but I don't find a way to include the grouping variable.

I could manually calculate the desired correlation but as I have a large data set and a lot of lags and values for the grouping variables, I would hope that there is a more elegant and faster way. Here is the manual calculation for the example above (lag 2, b=1):

```
sel <- which(data$b==1)
cor(data$a[sel[sel > 2]], data$a[sel[sel>2] - 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

If the time series object is a tsibble, the following works for me. Assuming the data frame is called df and the variable you are interested in is called var. You can specify max lag additionally

`df %>%  group_by(Region) %>% ACF(var, lag_max = 18) %>%  autoplot()`

Comment: Yeah, I was about to do something like `sapply(....)`  and your function. I am not aware of any other way since you cannot use `group_by` in your case

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer anyway! That's what I thought, too, but I hoped that someone else would havea better idea

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what information you are looking for but if you just want the acf values for multiple groups this should accomplish that. Some people have mentioned creating a `tidy` solution and this uses `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `purrr` to do grouped calculations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

sample_data <- dplyr::data_frame(group = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), size = 100, replace = T), value = sample.int(30, size = 100, replace = T)) 
head(sample_data)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   group value
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1     c    28
#> 2     c     9
#> 3     c    13
#> 4     c    11
#> 5     a     9
#> 6     c     9

grouped_acf_values <- sample_data %>%
  tidyr::nest(-group) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(acf_results = purrr::map(data, ~ acf(.x$value, plot = F)),
         acf_values = purrr::map(acf_results, ~ drop(.x$acf))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(acf_values) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(lag = seq(0, n() - 1))

head(grouped_acf_values)
#> Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
#> Groups: group [1]
#> 
#>   group  acf_values   lag
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <int>
#> 1     c  1.00000000     0
#> 2     c -0.20192774     1
#> 3     c  0.07191805     2
#> 4     c -0.18440489     3
#> 5     c -0.31817935     4
#> 6     c  0.06368096     5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at `split` to seperate your data.frame in buckets and then  `lapply` to apply your function to each group. Something like:

```
groups_data <- split(data, data$b)
groups_acf <- lapply(groups_data, acf,...)
```

Then you have to extract the required information from the output list for instance with `sapply(groups,acf, FUN=function(acfobject){acfobject$value})

For groups computations, I would also definitiely go with new ways "à la" Hadley Wickham with `%>%` operator and `group_by` ; studing that is on my todo list...

Comment: I think that this does not give the desired results. If I split the data, the lags are not correct anymore. For example, the observation with lag 1 for the first observation in the second group with b=1 would then be the last observation in the first group with b=1 but it sohuld be the last observation in the first group with b=3.

Comment: Ohhh... OK. wasn't careful on reading: 'value of b for t-2 does not matter...'